# Iteration process involving several functions

Tags: functions, numerics

I would like to carry out a following iteration process:
Apply function `f1[a_,b_,c_,d_]` to a starting list `l1={a1,b1,c1,d1}`, which will result in `l2={a2,b2,c2,d2}`. Then apply function `f2[a_,b_,c_,d_]` to list `l2` to get `l3={a3,b3,c3,d3}`. Finally apply function `f3[a_,b_,c_,d_]` to list `l3` to get `l4={a4,b4,c4,d4}`. As soon as this is over, I would like `{a4,b4,c4,d4}` to be the starting values of the process, in other words to start the procedure with values of `l4` obtained in the previous step. This should repeat until `l1` and `l4` in the same step are identical. It would be also good if I could get lists `l1`,...,`l4` from the last step returned at the end of the process. Any idea how can I do it in *Mathematica*?

I couldn't find a similar problem solved on the net. I read all about `FixedPoint`, `NestWhile` and `Fold` in the documentation, but I still don't know how to apply it to this problem, so I'd be grateful for all tips and advices.

Functions `f1`,...,`f3` are a bit complicated and involve reading values from dll library. Let's say they look like this one:

```
f1[{a_,b_,c_,d_}]:={
  afrombc[b-0.2,c],
  b-0.2,
  c,
  dfromab[afrombc[b-0.2,c],b-0.2]
}
```

`afrombc[]` and `dfromab[]` are predefined functions connected with dll library.

Comment: Please format your question (see the [format help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)) and supply (dummy) input, output and functions to show what you want to do.

Comment: Sounds like a plain `FixedPoint` application. In what way does `FixedPoint[f3[f2[f1[#]]] &, {a1, a2, a3, a4}]` or similar does not work for you?

Comment: Input is a problem in this case, even if it is supposed to be a dummy one. `FixedPoint[f3[f2[f1[#]]] &, {a1, a2, a3, a4}]` would mean that the iteration goes until `{a1, a2, a3, a4}` doesn't change in two subsequent steps?

Comment: But as long as your function (or chain of functions, which acts as one) converge, in principle the `FixedPoint` approach should work, right? Anything more specific will depend on you supplying working functions.

Comment: You're right, in principle it should work. I need  some time to play with it. I'll let You know as soon as I have something, but thanks for Your help so far.

Comment: I checked it on simplified functions and of course it works. It looks so easy now, that I'm embarassed by my original question. I guess what I was looking for was to write chain of functions using `f3[f2[f1[#]]] &` structure. All I need to do now is hope that my expanded mathematical model converges. Thanks @Yves Klett!

Comment: Not to worry - you showed real effort to update your question and it is great you were able to solve the problem! (Oh, and for chaining functions, you may also have a look at `Composition`).

Comment: I don't mind, while I'm still learning _Mathematica_ basics, I accept all kind of criticism :)

Comment: Decided for a short answer - let the others judge or even anwer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This calls for `FixedPoint`. I add `Composition` and pure functions for enhanced value (in case you have many functions and want to chain them conveniently). The dummy functions here are ultimate simpletons, but the principle works as long as inputs and outputs for the functions are compatible:

```
{f1, f2, f3} = {#^(1/2) &, #^(1/3) &, #^(1/4) &};

FixedPoint[Composition[f3, f2, f1][#] &, .1]
```

> ```
> 1.
> ```

Equivalent function calls would be:

```
FixedPoint[f3@f2@f1[#] &, .1]
```

or

```
FixedPoint[f3[f2[f1[#]]] &, .1]
```

Works also with lists in this case:

```
FixedPoint[Composition[f3, f2, f1][#] &, {0.1, .9, 1, 1.5}]
```

> {1., 1., 1, 1.}

but here for exact numbers other than `1`, you will be in trouble and you might want to use the third argument to `FixedPoint`, which defines the max. number of iterations:

```
FixedPoint[f3[f2[f1[#]]] &, 2, 20]
```

> ```
> 2^(1/4019988717840603673710821376)
> ```